# Objective-C: Problems accessing objects in other UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have a Custom UITableViewCell that holds a reference to its containing view controller (the VC that has its table in it).

```
//  MyCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet RootViewController *rootViewController;

-(IBAction)checkBoxClicked:(UIButton*)sender;


//  MyCell.m
@implementation MyCell

@synthesize rootViewController = _rootViewController;

-(IBAction)checkBoxClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self setCheckBoxChecked:!_checkBoxChecked];
    [_rootViewController refreshVisibleViewForCellTagged:self.tag];
}
```

In my cell I have a button that changes a variable and then calls a function in my rootViewController. The method is actually called however when I try to access any object in the RootViewController inside of the refreshVisibleViewForCellTagged method they are are '0x0' / nil;

```
//  RootViewController.h
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;


//  RootViewController.m
- (void) refreshVisibleViewForCellTagged:(NSInteger)cellTag
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.myTableView; // nil
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; // nil
    MyCell *selectedCell = (MyCell*)[self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // nil

    if (selectedCell.tag == cellTag) {
        NSLog(@"Refresh one way.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Do something else.");
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why I cant access any objects/variables in the RootController from within the method 'refreshVisibleViewForCellTagged'?

Please and thank you!

** My big question is **Why** can't I access any objects when calling a method in a view controller From a different view controller. There is some great programming truth that I am not aware of here, is it a permissions issue? Im not using @class (forward classing) in this instance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be subclassing the `UITableViewCellDelegate` protocol and generating feedback via the delegate model?

Comment: @Brooks - Yes I receive cellTag without any issue.

Comment: @trojanfoe - What Im trying to do with this method in the root view controller is to see if the currently selected cell (which has a detail view visible because RootView is a split screen showing 50% table and 50% view with labels) so if the currently selected cell was the cell where the checkbox was clicked then refresh the label in the view to reflect the new value of the checkbox. I dont know how a Delegate method would help me do such a custom task.

Comment: It won't make it any easier, but it will make your subclassed cell more reusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @trojanfoe said, delegation is a better way to do it.
Instead of `#import "RootViewController.h"`, it is better to adop delegation. Because `UITableViewCell` is a child and `RootViewController` is the parent view. You don't want the child to talk **directly** with the parent.

- To adopt delegation:
- in `MyCell.h` file
- remove `#import "RootViewController.h"`.
- revise `MyCell.h` as follows:

> ```
> @protocol MyCellDelegate; // if you need to have forward declaration
>
> @interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
> // @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet RootViewController *rootViewController;
> @property (nonatomic) id <MyCellDelegate> delegate;
> @end
>
> @protocol MyCellDelegate <NSObject>
> - (void)refreshVisibleViewForCellTagged:(NSInteger)cellTag;
> @end
> ```

- in `MyCell.m`.

> ```
> @synthesize delegate;
>
> -(IBAction)checkBoxClicked:(UIButton*)sender {
>      [self setCheckBoxChecked:!_checkBoxChecked];
>      //[_rootViewController refreshVisibleViewForCellTagged:self.tag];
>      [self.delegate refreshVisibleViewForCellTagged:self.tag];
> }
> ```

- in `RootViewController.h` adopt the delegation of MyCell

> ```
> #import "MyCell.h"
>
> @interface RootViewController : UIViewController <MyCellDelegate>
> ```

- in `RootViewController.m`.

> ```
> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>       UITableViewCell *cell = // your implementation
>       //assuming all your cells are of MyCell kind
>       // set RootViewController as the delegate of each cell
>       ((MyCell *)cell).delegate = self;
>
>       return cell;
> }
> ```

- implement the delegate method in `RootViewController.m`.

> ```
> - (void)refreshVisibleViewForCellTagged:(NSInteger)cellTag {
>      // whatever you have
> }
> ```

P.S. The above codes are for illustration. I didn't run them. If some part doesn't work, let me know, and I'll revise it.

The reason those objects in RootViewController are nil in the way you call, is because you are not accessing the same instance of RootViewController. It is a different (new) instance and hence all objects are nil.

Comment: OMG Face Palm - You are right Im not accessing the same instance of RootViewController -- In my company we try to keep as many references as possible in IB so that our designers can modify certain things without requiring a programmer -- So in Interface Builder in the xib that makes the Cell I added a new RootViewController and hooked it to _rootViewController so its a brand new instance. Im sorry to send you guys on a wild goose chase, thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, this is a poor design. For starters, your cell shouldn't need a reference to the view controller that the table it's in is in (read that twice, it barely makes sense just because the very idea of it is confusing). You have a strong reference to this view controller. So what happens when the OS tries to deallocate your view controller? It will never be able to, because the table view cell as a strong reference to it, keeping its retain count at 1. The same situation holds true for the cell. You risk running into a retain cycle here. Generally, child views should have weak references to their parents.

But this isn't even really a true parents/child relationship. I would suggest instead an approach like this, which all occurs in your view controller that contains the table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Assuming you set a reuse identifier "cellId" in the nib for your table view cell...
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellId"];
    if (!cell) {
        // If you didn't get a valid cell reference back, unload a cell from the nib
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id obj in nibArray) {
            if ([obj isMemberOfClass:[MyCell class]]) {
                // Assign cell to obj, and add a target action for the checkmark
                cell = (MyCell *)obj;
                [cell.checkMarkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkPressed:) forControlEvents:whateverEventYouWant];
                break;
            }
        }
     }
     // Set the tag of the cell here, since we may get a different cell back from the reuse queue
     cell.checkMarkButton.tag = indexPath.row;

     return cell;
}
```

Now set up the method for the clicking of the checkmark button

```
- (void)checkPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *checkmark = (UIButton *)sender;

    // This will give you the row of the checked button
    int checkedCellRow = checkmark.tag;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:checkedCellRow inSection:0];

    // Now you can grab a reference to that cell if you need to
    MyCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

This way, you keep all of the controller-related stuff in your controller class (i.e. how to handle the checkmark button being pressed), and you don't need to deal with this whackiness of referencing the view controller of your cell's table.

**EDIT:** I guess I should also help answer your questions...First of all, if you're saying that in your refreshVisibleViewForCell method, you're getting a nil value for self.myTableView, are you sure it is hooked up properly in IB? Even if it's hooked up, click the little x to unhook it and hook it up again to be sure. Also make sure you've @synthesized your myTableView property. Without seeing more code, an IB issue is my best guess as to why you're getting a nil value for tableView. A nil value here will result in a nil indexPath and selectedCell, also. As for your big question, you can access *properties* of objects within your view controller. Those properties can, of course, be objects. So in your example, if you have a tag property on selectedCell, you can access it from anywhere that you have a *valid* reference to selectedCell. If selectedCell is nil, the property will be nil. @class is better suited for header files. For instance, if you wanted to make your custom cell a property of your view controller, you might say:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MyCell;

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyCell *cell;

@end
```

Then, in your implementation file, you would actually import MyCell.h. Giving the @class forward declaration just keeps you from having to import all of the details about the MyCell class in your header file. The header doesn't need to know about all of the properties and methods of MyCell, just that you intend on using it in the implementation file. So you @class in the header, #import in the implementation.

Comment: I found that the nil issue was happening because I was not accessing the same instance of RootViewController that I wanted (I created a new one in interface builder) It was a noob mistake. However you are very right that this is not the best design and I am going to implement some of your suggestions to improve my code. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the fact that view controllers are even involved.  What you have are OBJECTS, connected together in a certain pattern.  Accessing data in another view controller is no different from accessing data in any other object.  There's no "magic" with view controllers, other than they have a few standardized connections to other objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing declarations of `myTableView` in your `RootViewController`. But if your `RootViewController` implements `UITableViewController`, you can use `self.tableView` to access the tableview. You don't need to keep a reference to it by yourself.

@RachelD, if your `RootView` is more complicated than just a `UITableViewController` consider using a separate class, such as `RootTableViewController`. Then in your `RootView` xib, create `IBOutlet` for `RootTableViewController` to reference it. Like this:

```
// RootTableViewController definition
@interface RootTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
}

// RootViewController definition
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController
{
    RootTableViewController *table_c;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet RootTableViewController *table_c;
```

Note that you need to drag an "Object" into the "Objects" section (for RootViewController) in the interface builder, and type `RootTableViewController` in the Custom Class section for this object. Right click this object, make sure its IBOutlet, view, 2 delegates are correctly set.

The reason why your `myTableView` is nil is because it's not properly initialized. I mean, if you don't use `UITableViewController` you are responsible for assigning it manually via interface builder or something.

Comment: (at)interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
(at)property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not deriving from ``UITableViewController``? By using ``UITableViewController``, you don't need to use IBOutlet to keep your own ``myTableView`` variable.

Comment: Its split with a table on half the screen and a changing view on the other half the screen. (iPad only app)

Comment: I've revised my answer, hopefully it makes more sense to you.

Comment: Oh I see make a new UITableViewController and add it to the existing RootViewController thats definatly do able. Wont this put me in the same situation though? The user clicks the checkbox on the UITableCell so the UITableCell's delegate pings the UITableViewController but then the UITableViewController still needs to pink the RootViewController to refresh the view in the rootView - and I cant access any variables in the rootView when calling its methods from other view controllers.

Comment: I'm thinking ``myTableView`` is nil because it's nil, i.e. you have not assigned a variable to it, or you haven't linked it in the interface builder. I don't think it has anything to do with "accessing variable in a parent controller", which is totally legal.

Comment: No its set because myTable is the table that is displaying myCell. Also there are more objects in RootViewController for example the array of myObjects that is used to fill myTable (an many more views/objects) when trying to access any of them, they are nil.

Comment: @RachelD is it possible that other part of your code have set it to nil?

Comment: I realized that its nil because I wasn't accessing the initialized copy of RootViewController but rather creating a brand new reference that hadn't been set up. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

---

in RootViewController.h:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
```

in RootViewController.m:

```
- (void) refreshVisibleViewForCellTagged:(NSInteger)cellTag {
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
MyCell *selectedCell = (MyCell*)[self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // nil
```

etc...

Comment: I do not want RootViewController to be a UITableViewController - Its split with a table on half the screen and a changing view on the other half the screen. (iPad only app)

Comment: Could you post the code which tells us where you are creating a property called myTableView?

Comment: I revised my original post to show RootViewController.h where the IBOutlet of myTable was added - theres also (at)synthesize. This variable is actually set in Interface Builder.

Comment: You could do this - since you are using IB you may want to access your child view controllers (UiTableView) as a member of the RootViewController:

`[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0]`