# Delegate to 'Parent' ViewController best practice

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

The setup:

PickerView (spinSelector) and label (chosenItem) added to ViewController.
Created separate delegate class files (SpinDelegate m&h) for the PickerView delegate.
Created instance of the delegate (SpinDelegate *mySpinDelegate)
Assigned delegate property to delegate instance

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    SpinDelegate *mySpinDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *chosenItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPickerView *spinSelector;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    mySpinDelegate=[[SpinDelegate alloc]init];

    self.spinSelector.delegate=mySpinDelegate;
    self.spinSelector.dataSource=mySpinDelegate;
}
```

**SpinDelegate.h**

```
@interface SpinDelegate : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    ChoiceData *choiceItems;
}

@end
```

**SpinDelegate.m**

```
    #pragma mark - PickerView Delegate
    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
titleForRow:(NSInteger)row 
forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

        return [choiceItems.choiceList objectAtIndex:row];
    }
```

Next is to use the method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

This is part of the `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol. Using this, to simply change the UILabel (chosenItem) in the `ViewController` to value of row. Something like "The picked item is %i",row

I've read and searched through a ton of posts and questions on `UIViewController` to `UIViewController` messaging and looked at protocol/delegate, singleton, `NSNotificationCenter`... it just seems to me that there is a syntax I am missing to address the parent/super?  The `ViewController` created the instance of the delegate, doesn't the delegate have scope?

Please educate me on this. : )

Comment: Delegates are basically protocols which sub class `NSObject` while you've used it as a sub-class of `UIViewController`. So even though you've named your class `SpinDelegate`, it isn't a delegate! Add the protocol to the `SpinDelegate` class.

Comment: Take a look at these two links, see if it helps you have a better understadning of delegation. They are not exactly what you wnat, but they show you the concept of messaging by delegate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996201/objective-c-problems-accessing-objects-in-other-uiviewcontrollers/9997323#9997323 and http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: tipycalFlow: I'm assigning it as delegate. (see mark in SpinDelegate.h and self.spinSelector.delegate=mySpinDelegate). The UIPickerViewDelegate protocol doesn't have any required methods.

Comment: @Canopus: Thanks...I will try the protocol/delegate approach for messaging the parent.  Didn't know if a delegate class delegating to another was a good pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import "SpinViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SpinViewControllerDelegate>
{
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *chosenItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPickerView *spinSelector;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)someFunction
{
    mySpinViewController=[[SpinViewController alloc]init];
    mySpinViewController.delegate=self;
    // show or present mySpinViewController
}

//implement the followed protocol's method
-(void) optionSelected:(NSString*)cellValue{

}
```

**SpinViewController.h**

```
@protocol SpinViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void) optionSelected:(NSString*)cellValue;
@end

@interface SpinViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    ChoiceData *choiceItems;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)id <SpinViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**SpinViewController.m**

```
-(void) pickerValueSelectedOrSimilarFn:(NSString*)cellValue{
  // this is how you give a callback to classes following the protocol
  [self.delegate optionSelected:cellValue];
}
```

Comment: I adopted similar and it works. It has cleared up how I think of delegates.  Thanks tipycalFlow.